# ZMQ messages not being received

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

Please forgive me if I'm missing something simple, this is my first time doing anything with messaging and I inherited this codebase from someone else.

I am trying to send a message from a windows machine with an IP of 10.10.10.200 to an Ubuntu machine with an IP of 10.10.10.15.

I got the following result when running TCPView from the Windows machine, which makes me suspect that the problem lies in the Ubuntu machine. If I'm reading that right, then my app on the windows machine has created a connection on port 5556 which is what it is supposed to do. In case I'm wrong, I'll include the windows code too.

```
my_app.exe  5436    TCP MY_COMPUTER 5556    MY_COMPUTER 0   LISTENING
```

Windows app code:

```
    void 
    NetworkManager::initializePublisher()
    {
        globalContext = zmq_ctx_new();

        globalPublisher = zmq_socket(globalContext, ZMQ_PUB);

        string protocol = "tcp://*:";
        string portNumber = PUBLISHING_PORT; //5556
        string address = protocol + portNumber;
        char *address_ptr = new char[address.size() + 1];
        strncpy_s(address_ptr, address.size() + 1, address.c_str(), address.size());

        int bind_res = zmq_bind(globalPublisher, address_ptr);
        if (bind_res != 0)
        {
            cerr << "FATAL: couldn't bind to port[" << portNumber << "] and protocol [" << protocol << "]" << endl;

        }
        cout << " Connection: " << address << endl;
    }

void 
NetworkManager::publishMessage(MESSAGE msgToSend)
{

    // Get the size of the message to be sent
    int sizeOfMessageToSend = MSG_MAX_SIZE;//sizeof(msgToSend);

    // Copy IDVS message to buffer
    char buffToSend[MSG_MAX_SIZE] = "";

    // Pack the message id
    size_t indexOfId = MSG_ID_SIZE + 1;
    size_t indexOfName = MSG_NAME_SIZE + 1;
    size_t indexOfdata = MSG_DATABUFFER_SIZE + 1;

    memcpy(buffToSend, msgToSend.get_msg_id(), indexOfId - 1);

    // Pack the message name
    memcpy(buffToSend + indexOfId, msgToSend.get_msg_name(), indexOfName - 1);

    // Pack the data buffer
    memcpy(buffToSend + indexOfId + indexOfName, msgToSend.get_msg_data(), indexOfdata - 1);

// Send message
    int sizeOfSentMessage = zmq_send(globalPublisher, buffToSend, MSG_MAX_SIZE, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

    getSubscriptionConnectionError();

    // If message size doesn't match, we have an issue, otherwise, we are good
    if (sizeOfSentMessage != sizeOfMessageToSend)
    {
        int errorCode = zmq_errno();
        cerr << "FATAL: couldn't not send message." << endl;
        cerr << "ERROR: " << errorCode << endl;
    }
}
```

I can include more of this side's code if you think it's needed, but the error is popping up on the Ubuntu side, so I'm going to focus there.

The problem is when I call zmq_recv it returns -1 and when I check zmq_errno I get EAGAIN (Non-blocking mode was requested and no messages are available at the moment.) I also checked with netstat and I didn't see anything on port 5556

First is the function to connect to the publisher, then the function to get data, followed by main.
Ubuntu side code:

```
void
*connectoToPublisher()
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB);

    string protocol = "tcp://";
    string ipAddress = PUB_IP;      //10.10.10.15
    string portNumber = PUB_PORT;  // 5556
    string address = protocol + ipAddress + ":" + portNumber;
    cout << "Address: " << address << endl;

    char *address_ptr = new char[address.size() + 1];
    strcpy(address_ptr, address.c_str());

    // ------ Connect to Publisher ------
    bool isConnectionEstablished = false;
    int connectionStatus;
    while (isConnectionEstablished == false)
    {
        connectionStatus = zmq_connect(subscriber, address_ptr);

        switch (connectionStatus)
        {
        case 0: //we are good.
            cout << "Connection Established!" << endl;
            isConnectionEstablished = true;
            break;
        case -1:
            isConnectionEstablished = false;
            cout << "Connection Failed!" << endl;
            getSubscriptionConnectionError();
            cout << "Trying again in 5 seconds..." << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Hit default connecting to publisher!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (isConnectionEstablished == true)
        {
            break;
        }
        sleep(5); // Try again
    }

    // by the time we get here we should have connected to the pub
    return subscriber;
}

static void *
getData(void *subscriber)
{
    const char *filter = ""; // Get all messages
    int subFilterResult = zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter, strlen(filter));
    // ------ Get in main loop ------
    while (1)
    {
        //get messages from publisher
        char bufferReceived[MSG_MAX_SIZE] = "";
        size_t expected_messageSize = sizeof(bufferReceived);
        int actual_messageSize = zmq_recv(subscriber, bufferReceived, MSG_MAX_SIZE, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);

        if (expected_messageSize == actual_messageSize)
        {
            MESSAGE msg = getMessage(bufferReceived); //Uses memcpy to copy id, name, and data strutct data from buffer into struct of MESSAGE
        if (strcmp(msg.get_msg_id(), "IDXY_00000") == 0)
        {
            DATA = getData(msg); //Uses memcpy to copy data from buffer into struct of DATA
        }
    } else

        {
            // Something went wrong
            getReceivedError(); //This just calls zmq_errno and cout the error
        }
        usleep(1);
    }
    }

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
//Doing some stuff...

void *subscriber_socket = connectoToHeadTrackerPublisher();

// Initialize Mux Lock

pthread_mutex_init(&receiverMutex, NULL);

// Initializing some variables...

// Launch Thread to get updates from windows machine
pthread_t publisherThread;
pthread_create(&publisherThread,
        NULL, getData, subscriber_socket);

// UI stuff

zmq_close(subscriber_socket);
return 0;
}
```

If you cannot provide a solution, then I will accept identifying the problem as a solution. My main issue is that I don't have the knowledge or experience with messaging or networking to correctly identify the issue. Typically if I know what is wrong, I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ok, this has nothing to do with signalling / messaging framework

Your Ubuntu code instructs the ZeroMQ `Context()`-instance engine to create a new `SUB`-socket instance and next the code insist this socket to try to **`_connect()`** ( to setup a `tcp://` transport-class connection towards the peering counterparty ) to "opposite" access-point, sitting on an address of the Ubuntu `localhost:port#` that was setup as **`10.10.10.15:5556`**, while the intended **`PUB`**-side archetype access-point actually lives not on this Ubuntu machine, but on another, Windows host, `IP:port#` of which is **`10.10.10.200:5556`**

This seems to be the root-cause of the problem, so change it accordingly to match the physical layout and you may get the toys work.

Comment: So what you're saying is to try setting the PUB_IP in the connectToPublisher function on the Ubuntu machine to 10.10.10.200? I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Program not completely working, but wireshark is showing messages going back and forth so I'm going to mark this question answered. If you're interested in continuing to help, the issue is zmq_recv is returning -1 and zmq_errno is returning EAGAIN

Comment: Got it working 100%. Not sure why, but zmq_recv in don't wait mode was not receiving the messages. Once we took that off, it all started working.